# dump memory in android

Tags: java, android, security

sorry, anyone here do you know about dump memory on android system? I knew that we could get information for these files and used them. But i don't know exactly what is the dump memory. how was it created? when is it? how can we get those files and access it? My propose I want to understand clearly about dump memory that I want to create a general security system to protect this file on android system, but this is the next step of my study.

Thank you so much for your appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dumping Dex file on memory or most researchers will call unpacking of android application. The technique is quite sample, they just modified some files on android source code such as: DexClassLoader, Method(), Invok(),etc. the target application will be installed into a device or emulator with customized android OS and then they will run the target application and boom... the target application is dumped and the attacker can get the dex file and use it later. If someone interested how it works you can find in google as the keyword: Unpacking android application.

Answer (score 1):

A memory dump is a process in which the contents of memory are displayed and stored in case of an application or system crash. Memory dump helps software developers and system administrators to diagnose, identify and resolve the problem that led to application or system failure.

You can learn to dump the memory of android at http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-hacking-dumping-and-analyzing-applications-memory/#gref